# Connecting UIButton1 with UIButton2 by calling method of UIButton2 in the method of UIButton1

Tags: iphone, uibutton

To Connect UIButton1 with UIButton2, calling method of UIButton2 in the method of UIButton1,  makes UIButton1 acts like UIButton2 which is not what requirement is. UIButton1 is only acting as UIButton2.

UIButton1 is rewind Button

```
-(void)rewind:(id)sender{
audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
[timer invalidate];
ContainerViewController *viewController = [[[ContainerViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
[self playpauseAction:_playButton];
}
```

UIButton2 is play pause button

```
-(void)playpauseAction:(id)sender {

if([audioPlayer isPlaying])
{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Play Icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[audioPlayer pause];
[self pauseTimer];
[self pauseLayer:self.view.layer];

 }else{
[sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"52.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[audioPlayer play];
[self resumeTimer];
[self resumeLayer:self.view.layer];

 if(isFirstTime == YES)
{
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:11.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(displayviewsAction:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];
    isFirstTime  = NO;
}} }
```

Requirement is that UIButton1 should act as UIButton1 and UIButton2 should act as UIButton2 when UIButton2 method is called in UIButton1 method.

Technically requirement is when rewind button is pressed and as it is playing audio file from the beginning so there should be option available to pause. So if i don't call UIButton2 method in UIButton1 method then i don't have pausing option available for users. So that is the reason of calling UIButton2 method in UIButton1 method.

So when rewind button is pressed then it will toggle play button to pause button which is fine but just for testing purposes if you press rewind button again it pauses which means it is acting as play pause button and if you press rewind button again then it will play from the beginning.

How can i stop UIButton1 from acting as UIButton2.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's a bit complicated to follow your description, but as I understand you want that the playback gets paused on rewind, so that the user can press play again.

You just need to check, if you're playing at the moment, before toggling the button.

```
if([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
  [self playpauseAction:_playButton];
}
```

So it will only pause the playback and show the play button again. Is that what you want?

Comment: In my case problem i m having is that play pause button is working fine specially when i m using its method in rewind method. My problem is that rewind button is also acting as play pause button i think because i m calling play pause method in rewind method. So basically want rewind method to act only as rewind method but at the same time want play pause button to toggle so that user will have pause option.